# Hyperledger-Composer: composer network start error:Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT Command failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

After I created a program and finished the model design/ query.qry / acl. I tested it at local playground and it ran successfully. When I tried to create the admin card (run composer network start), I failed. It launched a ccenv peer without response.

I couldn't find any other similar mistake in Google. It confuses me.

Expected Behavior
Composer network start command should run successfully. And the admin card should created properly.

Actual Behavior
Failed to create card. And launched a weird peer with a random name.
When I try to run again:composer network start -n cmusic -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -V 0.0.1 -A admin -S adminpw
It said that it's already been launched.

Possible Fix
I don't know why and how to fix it. I tried reload the environment but the same mistake still exists.

```
cielo@cielo-ThinkPad-E550:~/cprogrames/cmusic/dist$ composer network start -n cmusic -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -V twork start -n cmusic -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -V start -n cmusic -cadmin
Starting business network cmusic at version 0.0.1

Processing these Network Admins:
userName: admin

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
Command failed

cielo@cielo-ThinkPad-E550:~/cprogrames/cmusic/dist$ composer network start -n cmusic -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -V twork start -n cmusic -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -V start -n cmusic -cadmin
Starting business network cmusic at version 0.0.1

Processing these Network Admins:
userName: admin

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: failed to execute transaction f3d0e4a4cfa31b72766e4to execute transaction f3d0e4a4cfa31b72766e4ecute transaction f48e83o register cmusic:0.0.1 haincode cmusic3d0e4a4cfa31b72766e4a4cfa31b72766e475ec4b1ab48e83o register cmuhainc
Command failed
```

my composer is v0.20.8,my Docker version is 18.09.4, build d14af54
node -v8.15.1
npm -v6.4.1

these are my peers:

```
f818aed96671 hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.2.1 "peer node start" 2 days ago Up 2 days 0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp peer0.org1.example.com
57989248aadd hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.2.1 "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…" 2 days ago Up 2 days 0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp ca.org1.example.com
447556b93e71 hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:0.4.10 "tini -- /docker-ent…" 2 days ago Up 2 days 4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp couchdb
45b9da98c156 hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.2.1 "orderer" 2 days ago Up 2 days 0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp orderer.example.com
```

Comment: Have you initialized the channel ?

Comment: Yes,I did that by running the script of composer: startFabric.sh  @Boo

Comment: Try running the stopFabric.sh script then tearDownFabric.sh . After that again
startFabric.sh then
createPeerAdminCard.sh

Comment: I've tried it. And I also have tried:docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
docker container prune

Comment: I create a program carefully(most of them are the default ), at first the problem still exist. But now it launch the dev container successfully. I don't know why.

Comment: It happens to me once in a while too. I just restart and it fixes itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. The key is that there can only be one chaincode in the network at the same time. If you deploy multiple at the same time, this error will occur.

Try these two and restart the network.

`docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
docker container prune`